# 2 vertices connected two times with the same edge on lightweight mode

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

The [orientdb documentation](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Lightweight-Edges.html) says regarding lightweight edges:

> two vertices are connected by maximum 1 edge, so if you already have one edge between two vertices and you're creating a new edge between the same vertices, the second edge will be regular

Looking at the following script:

```
drop database plocal:../databases/test-lightweight admin admin;

create database plocal:../databases/test-lightweight  admin admin;
connect plocal:../databases/test-lightweight admin admin;

alter database custom useLightweightEdges=true;

// Vertices
CREATE class    Driver extends V;
CREATE PROPERTY Driver.name    STRING;

// Edges
CREATE class    Knows extends E;
CREATE PROPERTY Knows.in   LINK Driver  MANDATORY=true;
CREATE PROPERTY Knows.out  LINK Driver  MANDATORY=true;

// DATA
CREATE VERTEX Driver SET name = 'Jochen';
CREATE VERTEX Driver SET name = 'Ronnie';

// Jochen and Ronnie are very good friends
CREATE EDGE Knows FROM (SELECT FROM Driver WHERE name = 'Jochen') to (SELECT FROM Driver WHERE name = 'Ronnie');
CREATE EDGE Knows FROM (SELECT FROM Driver WHERE name = 'Jochen') to (SELECT FROM Driver WHERE name = 'Ronnie');

SELECT expand(out()) FROM (SELECT FROM Driver WHERE name = 'Jochen'); // 2 times Ronnie
SELECT count(*) FROM Knows; // 0
```

I would expect the last count to return 1, but it returns 0.

When I execute the same script but disabling the lightweight mode the result is 2 (as expected).